# Twitter Bootstrap: Resize number input to fit contents on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a number input field. I want to start with a minimum width so that the input fits the default value of  -1. As the value decreases to -100,-1,000, etc or increases I want the input width to adjust so that the entire field is visible.

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 input-group ">
   <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input name="childPrice" id="childPrice" type="number" step=".25" value="-1" min="-99999" max="-1" class="form-control"  onchange="$(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);" size="9"> 
   <span class="input-group-addon">/ticket</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your method works if you use type="text" but I am guessing you want to use number.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be to use a monospaced font, then pre-calculate the width of one character, then add a change handler on the field which would dynamically set its width depending on how many characters it needs to contain.

The slightly harder way would be to also have a change handler which would take the value of the text field, use it to create a detached node with `display: none`, insert it into the DOM, measure its width, then use that value to dynamically resize the field.

Here is a proof of concept on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/uVJ6L/

JS:

```
$('#my-text').on('keyup', function(ev){
    var field = $(ev.currentTarget),
        origWidth = field.outerWidth(),
        width = 0,
        val = field.val(),
        tmp = $('<p style="display:none;">' + val + '</p>');

    $('body').append(tmp);
    width = tmp.outerWidth();
    tmp.remove();
    if (width > origWidth)
        field.css('width', width);
});
```

Comment: I worked off of your idea to come up with the following: http://jsfiddle.net/uVJ6L/2/

Comment: Yeah that works fine for the most part but I do see a couple problems.  First of all, the 'change' event only fires once when they leave (blur) the field.  I'm not sure if that's what you wanted or you wanted it to constantly expand as they type, for which case you would need the 'keyup' event. The other thing is that it assumes a constant width of 15 for each character, which isn't strictly accurate.

Comment: I think that you missed that I am using a number input type. You're right that I do need the keyup event for when the user types in the input. But my original logic was only considering using the up and down arrows to change the field. the change fires whenever the button is held down or clicked.